# What is the typical and example use of an "L-moment" as contrasted to a conventional moment?

Tags: moments, l-moments

I have seen moments a few times, but I am unfamiliar with "[L-moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-moment)".

What are they used for?  What do they do that other things, like classical moments, cannot do as well?